# Total Sum of two columns and show in the third Column

Tags: sql

I have a Three columns in the SQL table,

I want to show the sum of the total of two columns in the third column. How can I show that using SQL query.

This is my table structure

```
Id  int Unchecked
Col_A    int    Unchecked
Col_B    int    Unchecked
Total     int   Checked
```

Comment: Do you want to select the sum or store the sum in the table?

Comment: Check out GROUP BY combined with the aggreagte function SUM, and then do a UNION ALL.

Comment: @juergend I want to store the sum in the `total` column

Comment: @jarlh: How can we do that ?

Comment: Then you need triggers that update the column value if one of the other changes

Comment: You don't have a total column as far as I can see. You have a row total. But never store computed values in your db, it will only cause you trouble (data inconsistency).

Comment: @juergend: Ok, agree with you.! What will be the query than ?

Comment: @jarlh: I have a column with name `total` you can see the question

Comment: @Nadeem whats your findings

Comment: @POHH: I want to show the total value in the total column using `SQL`

Comment: @jarlh: Sure..!! will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comuted column for this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [a] [INT] NULL,
    [b] [INT] NULL,
    [c]  AS ([a]+[b])
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Test
        ( a, b )
VALUES  ( 1, -- a - int
          2  -- b - int
          )


SELECT * FROM dbo.Test 

Results:
a   b   c
1   2   3
```

Comment: Also giorgi, what if I want to show the total for each column. Lets take for column A has 10 records. `1+ 1+ 1+ ...` and at the last I have to show the total of these `10` records, how to show that ?

Comment: @Nadeem - You need to ask a new question and also you should show some effort to solve your problem

Comment: SELECT SUM(c) FROM dbo.Test WHERE --apply appropriate filters

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: It is showing sum of `a + b` I want only for a

Comment: I think you shoul read some book first of all :)
SELECT SUM(a) FROM dbo.Test WHERE --apply appropriate filters

Comment: Ok sure..!! I got that. and what will be the query for total column same as for `a` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68859/discussion-between-nadeem-and-giorgi-nakeuri).

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I want to the SUM of multiple columns in to one column  and the column name is dynamic

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to store the total in the table, you can simply calculate it as part of your SQL query as follows:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Col_A,
    Col_B,
    Col_A + Col_B AS Total
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my table where the colums are salary and variable.

[image]

Now i need the sum of basic and variable as total.
**Here is the query for that-**

```
select basic,variable,(basic+variable) as total from salary
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the given table:]

[image: After performing the following query]

[image]

or if you just want to display total:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try the following -

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD colC AS ColA * ColB
```